# How to calculate p-value comparing bootstrap-based predicted probabilities and observed probabilities

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, bootstrap, resampling

I posted this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208144/how-to-calculate-p-value-comparing-bootstrap-based-predicted-probabilities-and-o) first but I have got no answer so far, so I decided to post it here in the hope that here I might get an answer. I hope my procedure is acceptable.

Essentially, what I want is any help to calculate bootstrap- and permutation-based p-values comparing the observed probability and the predicted probability.

**#data:**

```
ldose <- rep(0:5, 2)
numdead <- c(1, 4, 9, 13, 18, 20, 0, 2, 6, 10, 12, 16)
sex <- factor(rep(c("M", "F"), c(6, 6)))
SF <- cbind(numdead, numalive = 20-numdead)
dat<-data.frame(ldose, numdead, sex, SF)
tibble::rowid_to_column(dat, "indices")
new.data <- data.frame(ldose = 20, sex = "F")
```

**#bootstrap:**

```
temp.out<-function(dat, indices, new.data) {
     d<-dat[indices, ] 
     f<- glm(SF ~ sex*ldose, family = binomial (link = logit), data = d)  
     return(predict(f, new.data, type="response"))
}

results <- boot::boot(dat, temp.out, 1000, sim = "permutation")

boot::boot.ci(results, conf = c(0.90, 0.95), type = c("perc"))
```

**#questions:**

```
#boot::boot.ci(results, conf = 0.95, type = "all") #why is this failing?
#how should I proceed to calculate bootstrap-based p-value 
comparing the observed probability(e.g., 0.45) and 
the predicted probabilities (based on the bootstrap algorithm above)?
```

Thanks in advance for any help. If anything is not clear, please kindly let me know in the comments.